# Chrome weird behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I have some bugs with Chrome. Since a few weeks ago the placeholders don't behave, when I click on the input the placeholder should be hidden, but it stays there until I type. And also the location.href in js scripts don't work. When I click a link I should be redirected but nothing happens since I noticed the placeholder bug.

What could be the problem ? I tried reinstalling Chrome but that didn't fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://crbug.com/106714, the placeholder thing is expected behavior. And what is wrong with your `location.href`? Do you have a test case? If that's a real bug, search for one on http://crbug.com and file and new one at http://new.crbug.com if none has been filed yet.

Comment: Thanks for the placeholder solution, I managed to make it work as before. As for location.href, I will search for it.